# Remove padding bottom for height:auto

Tags: html, css, padding

I am facing a issue happened to css coding. I really need help in this issue. Cut the story short, i have a **div** for image and this is the **div** i wanted for a sliding banners as well. But, i am wondering why there would have a padding below the image within the **div** if i set the height as auto(i set height as auto because of i want to make a responsive layout). No matter how i set 0 padding to the **div** for the image, it won't work. I have provided a link to see the image or to see the live site. Link to attachment http://www.ncc.my/resources/padding-issue.jpg or link to site http://www.ncc.my(this site is still in progress).

The css code i have for the div is:

```
#contentContainer .slides {width:1140px; height:auto float:left; background:#666;}
#contentContainer .slides img {width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px)
{
#contentContainer .slides {width:100%;}
}
```

If i set the height to the specified height i want, the layout is perfect. But, when i set again the height as **auto**, definitely there will be the issue would happen as shown in attachment. Any solution to get this resolved? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display: block` on your image.  So your CSS will be

```
#contentContainer .slides img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block; /* Add this */
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Pattle, bravo! Thanks for your solution! You helped me in this. I didn't think of adding "display:block" to "#contentContainer .slides img {}". But i added to "#contentContainer .slides {}" only. That was why it won't work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting height:100% instead of auto.  This answer is more a shot in the dark I'm not sure if it will do the trick.

Comment: Hi Skrhee, i tried this as well. I am still working on it to get this work.